# Promise {<pending>} al tratar de retornar el valor de una promesa

Tags: javascript, axios, promesas

Estoy tratando de retornar el valor en una promesa pero recibo el siguiente dato

Promise {< pending >}

mi codigo es el siguiente

```
const respuesta  = axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/parts/part/${this.codigo}`)
respuesta.then((response) => {return response.data.exists}) //<--Aqui reciboPromise {< pending >}
//En la promesa me retorna un booleano ya sea true o false el cual pretendo utilizar en un if y asignar logica 

if (respuesta) {
//logica } 
else {
//logica
}
```

No tengo mucha experiencia en las promesas y estoy tratando de entender como funcionan si pudieran apoyarme gracias
saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que las peticiones a APIs son asíncronas, es decir, cuando realizas una petición, el código puede seguir avanzando sin haber obtenido la respuesta de la misma (te la puede dar durante la petición, al final de la petición o nunca).

En tu caso, es lo que está pasando, te está retornando una promesa.

Tu problema tiene una solución fácil:

```javascript
const APIRequest = async () => {
    const respuesta  = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/parts/part/${this.codigo}`)
    await respuesta.then((response) => {return response.data.exists}); 
} // Como sólo pones un trozo de código, te he encapsulado todo en una función para añadir async al método.
if (respuesta) {
//logica } 
else {
//logica
}
```

Como puedes ver, el código está exactamente igual, pero con dos palabras claves dentro.

1. Async: Avisa al compilador que la función es asíncrona (por cada tick de reloj del procesor no tiene porqué ejecutar una instrucción).
2. Await: Debe estar acompañada por async, toda función o variable que tenga esta palabra clave, no seguirá ejecutando código hasta que se haya obtenido la respuesta.

Con estas dos soluciones, tu código ya debería ser funcional.

Pero, en el caso de que no funcionara, te recomiendo realizar el siguiente cambio:

```javascript
const APIRequest = async () => {
    const respuesta  = axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/parts/part/${this.codigo}`)
    respuesta.then((response) => {
        let respuesta = response.data.exists;
        if (respuesta) {
          //logica 
        } else {
          //logica
        }
    });
}
```

Es decir, mover el if/else dentro del .then de la petición a la api.